# constructor through inheritance

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

so I'm trying out an example of using a constructor with inheritance but the remix ide is returning an error, which isn't the case on the course I'm following. Any idea of what might be causing the error or if there's an update with the newer solidity versions?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract myConstruct {
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name) {
        name = _name;
    }
}

contract mySecondConstruct is myConstruct {
    constructor (string memory _name) myConstruct(_name) {} ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon `;` doesn't belong after the block. (Empty block in your case `{}`)

Correct syntax:

```
// remove the semicolon
constructor (string memory _name) myConstruct(_name) {}
```